# Why is vectors A.B expressed in the form of $a_xb_x +a_yb_y +a_zb_z$ in the dot product?

Tags: vectors

I don't know how to put the subscript x and y there....but I hope that you will know what I mean. I understand the other definition of the dot product involving cos...but not this one. How is this way derived? Can someone help me make intuitive sense of this? Why must we add the xyz components?

Another question is why the dot product is a scalar quantity? If I resolve vector $A$ to a vector $B$, shouldn't I get a new magnitude in the direction of vector $B$?

Comment: Have you ever taken elementary linear algebra?

Comment: It is defined like that and it can be derived that it equals $|A||B|\cos\theta$ where $|.|$ denotes the norm and $\theta$ the angle between $A$ and $B$. I seems that you are switching "definition" and "derivation" wich can will do no harm here. In both cases the outcome is not a vector but a scalar. Its definition determines what it is: apparantly a scalar magnitude and not a vector. You just have to live with that.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Equivalence_of_the_definitions

Comment: I am taking a level maths now

Answer (score 1):

Well, in a general way the dot product is an operation defined between two objects that satisfies some properties (check out this page on wikipedia for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), for a 3D vector it turns out that if you define the dot product as: 
$$ \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B} = a_xb_x + a_yb_y + a_zb_z  $$ 
these properties are fullfilled. 
Note that $ a_xb_x + a_yb_y + a_zb_z  $ is ascalar and not a vector anymore, because you are summing up products between scalar quantities (i.e. the components of your vectors).

Now consider the dot product between the vector $ \mathbf{A}= a_x \mathbf{i} + a_y \mathbf{j} + a_z \mathbf{k} $ and the vector $  \mathbf{i} $, using the formula above, you get: 
$$ \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{i} = a_x = \mid \mathbf{A} \mid cos\theta  $$ 
where $\theta$ is the angle between $  \mathbf{A} $ and $  \mathbf{i} $, i.e. $ \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{i}$ gives you the projection of $ \mathbf{A} $ on $\mathbf{i} $ (try to sketch the vectors in 2D). 
So, in a general way, you have that $ \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}  $ gives you the projection of $\mathbf{A} $ on $\mathbf{B}$, i.e $ \mid \mathbf{A} \mid \mid \mathbf{B} \mid cos\theta  $.

Comment: Hmmm...so according to Wikipedia, the A.B thing is a definition...is that it? Or the proof lies in the A.i thing?

Comment: Take it as a definition. The example of $ \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{i} $ hepls to visualize geometrically the meaning of the dot product and understand the relation between the two formulas: A⋅B=axbx+ayby+azbz and A⋅B=∣A∣∣B∣cosθ